# Why NodeJS/Socket call so many times

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

My problem is when the user goes to a site like /top, I want to get the top users.

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("/top") > -1) {
    app.website.socket.emit('loadTopDailyCases');
}
```

I emit `loadTopDailyCases` to get the `TopCases` back. 
But for any reason, he calls that so much times, that the loading time loads sometimes very very long and I see in log that he try to load much times...

That's the Server side. He give `TopCases` (an array) back

```
socket.on('loadTopDailyCases', function() {
    socket.emit('topdailycases', TopCases);
});
```

But that will called so much times than, but I don't know why.

If I call the first emit with a timeout, the system calls only one time and it's fast done. But why only with timeout?

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("/top") > -1) {
    setTimeout(function() { app.website.socket.emit('loadTopDailyCases'); }, 500); 
}
```

With that it call one time and done.
But I don't understand why.

Outside of every jQuery functions is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

So I wthat all will run when document is ready but I don't know why he calls that function so many times and with the timeout it works.

Answer (score 0):

It was the Socket.io Version!

Install Socket.io Version 1.7.3 than it works!